# vobrpc_server.exe(7616): Error: Error from VOB database: "\MYVOB"

Tags: clearcase, vob

Error encountered while loading component in snapshot views and corresponding vobrpc error says:

```
vobrpc_server.exe(7600): Error: Error from VOB database: "\MYVOB".
vobrpc_server.exe(7600): Error: db_VISTA error -901 (errno == "Invalid argument")
vobrpc_server.exe(7600): Error: DBMS error in C:\CCVOB\MYVOB.vbs\db.
vobrpc_server.exe(7600): Error: DBMS error in "\atria\lib\db\db__elem.c" line 162
```

The specific error "`db_VISTA error -901 (errno == "Invalid argument")`" is no where mentioned in the IBM support docs, however other 901 error are mentioned in the below link .

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21248861#error-901

Can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The main documentation for Vob access error is "[Error from VOB database and Trouble opening VOB database](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21135964)".

To gather the most information about the issue, it is best to check the logs  of the view logs (not just the vobrpc logs). Also check the logs both on the client and the server.

A [901 error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21248861#error-901) suggests an error on the Vob server side regarding accessing the vob itself (either in term of resource or permission).
You can check first if the UCM component is visible through a dynamic view (instead of loading it with a snapshot view).

A daily reboot of the vob server suggests issue with the parameters of said server.
You can start tweaking first the ones of the [lock manager](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21294517) (`-u` and `-q`).

Comment: when the vobserver is rebooted, the issue gets resolved. What could be reason for this ? This happens almost every day, and every day reboot resolves the issue. Any comment on this ?

Comment: @user181369 and if you create a new snapshot view, do you reproduce the issue? For that specific component? Or for any component?

Comment: This behavior is not specific to a vob. sometime for one vob some time for others. But when the vobserver is rebooted, it works.

Comment: @user181369 Ok. Maybe updating -u and -q for the lock manager can help the vob server. See my updating answer. Check the db_server_log .