# Unable to launch clear case admin console in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: clearcase

I had an issue where the servers `D:` drive is corrupted completely and `D:` drive was hosed CearCase application. And we have restored `D:` drive from backup.

Now the problem is, from local admin account, I am able to launch `ccadminconsole.msc` without any issue, but from domain user login I am getting below error.

[image]

Does anyone know the cause and fix for this ?

The only error I could see from Application log is this:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ClearCase
Date:          4/11/2017 11:06:06 AM
Event ID:      1024
Task Category: VOBRPC
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          OIM\cc_albd_sj_agile
Computer:      S09CGP.us.oim.com
Description:
vobrpc_server.exe(4980): Error: Trouble opening VOB database: "\Xpedia".
```

Comment: That error is highly unlikely to be related, you may get more information out of a process monitor log, if only to see what happened. You may also want to check your VOBs, since the second message makes me wonder if the databases are damaged or inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

As [I mentioned in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23753013/6309):

> The main documentation for Vob access error is "[Error from VOB database and Trouble opening VOB database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23753013/6309)".
>
> To gather the most information about the issue, it is best to check the logs  of the view logs (not just the `vobrpc` logs). Also check the logs both on the client and the server.

So check both with the [`cleartool getlog` command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_getlog.htm), both for your own computer, and for the ClearCase VOB server.
Check also the `db` log, for any `db_VISTA database` error you could find there. And the `mvfs` log, just in case.

Typically, especially after a backup restore, the main cause of this problem may be related to the permissions on the VOB storage directory, in which case a [`cleartool fix_prot` (as I do here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29920242/6309) is the first thing to try.
Make sure first your local account is part of the right `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`, which should match the main group for the Vob.